# django translation not working by django-rosetta

Tags: django, translation, django-rosetta

I have installed the django-rosetta for translation, made .po and .mo files through django command

> django-admin.py makemessages -l ar

and translate all words through django-rosetta,

now when i change my language to Arabic from English, it show some words in Arabic and some in English, although i have translated all these words in Arabic,

Comment: version info about what django version you're using might help

Answer (score 1):

Have you restarted you web server?

> This means your project's labels will be translated right away, unfortunately you'll still have to restart the webserver for the changes to take effect. (NEW: if your webserver supports it, you can force auto-reloading of the translated catalog whenever a change was saved. See the note regarding the ROSETTA_WSGI_AUTO_RELOAD variable in conf/settings.py.

-- http://code.google.com/p/django-rosetta/

Comment: Right now I am on django development server :-( but anyhow, I have restarted it as well

Comment: When you are in rossetta, do you see any of the translated strings marked as fuzzy? If yes, make sure that the translations are still correct and uncheck the fuzzy flag.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of server are you running?

I had the same problem with Apache2 and FastCGI. I had to restart the FastCGI Process to see the modifications.

Have you added the local path properly to your settings?

```
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.split(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))[0]
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, "locale"),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have translations marked as fuzzy? (In Rosetta you can filter to display only fuzzy translations.) If some strings are fuzzy, make sure they are properly translated, uncheck the fuzzy flag and save the translations.

Another reason for translations not showing up could be that some python formatting strings (e.g. 'My %s apple') are not properly reproduced in the translated string. If formatting codes are unbalanced Rosetta should warn you, and the actual translation doesn't get written to the file.

Comment: then how should i translate  'My %s apple' this kind of string?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I encountered with this problem in Django v3. After I updated it to Django v4.1+ , It worked.